# Creating an Association With an Entity Super Class Using JPA

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have a simple class hierarchy of entities like so:

```
Permissable  (super class)
\
 PermissableResource (sub class)
```

They are persisted in a table like so:

```
Permissable
-------------
id          PK
resource    FK Resource(resourceId)
```

I have another entity called `Resource` that I want to create an association with. It is persisted in a table like so:

```
Resource
-------------
resourceId    PK
```

In my `PermissableResource` class, I create the association like so:

```
@JoinColumn(name="resource", referencedColumnName="resourceId")
@ManyToOne
Resource resource;
```

The issue comes with the Resource class. I would like to have a reference to the super class `Permissable` and not the subclass `PermissableResource`. I try to create the association like so:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="resource", cascade= CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity=PermissableResource.class)
private Permissable permissiable;
```

But this causes the following error on deployment:

```
Exception Description: The attribute [permissiable] in entity class [class com.dv.oa.model.entity.resource.Resource] has a mappedBy value of [resource] which does not exist in its owning entity class [class com.dv.oa.model.entity.permission.permissable.Permissable]. If the owning entity class is a @MappedSuperclass, this is invalid, and your attribute should reference the correct subclass.. Please see server.log for more details.
```

Its looking in `Permissable` for the association and not in `PermissableResource`

I thought that since I use the `targetEntity` attribute of `@OneToOne` and point it at `PermissableResource.class` this would work. How can I keep a super class reference in my entity, but map it to the subclass?

Comment: If `Permissable` can be abstract, [inheritance](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance) is the option I suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that in `PermissableResource` you defined a `@ManyToOne` relationship, whereas in the `Resource` class you defined a `@OneToOne`. Try substituting the latter with `@OneToMany`.

Comment: Nice catch, let me give that a shot